# Unable to update Avro record

Tags: avro

I have created a new avro datafile and wrote records into it. I am able to read the records also but I want to update a particular record , can you please help me with this ? I have tried the below code for updating the record but it simply appends it as a new record

```
private void update(GenericRecord record) throws IOException {
    Schema schema = getSchema();
    DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new   GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(
            schema);

    DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<GenericRecord>(
            writer);
    dataFileWriter.appendTo(file);      
    dataFileWriter.close();

}

// call to update method
if(record.get("empId").toString().equals("123")) {
            record.put("empDesg", "SSE");
            update(record);
        }
```

Comment: Avro is not like database, its just a way to serialize your objects. Hence, no updates. To update records, you can create a new file and write a small utility to merge those two file.

Comment: @tesnik03 : thank you for your answer.. this makes sense..